# Troubleshooting an AutoDock Vina error on Chimera: “Could not find an atomic number for Hn Hn”

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-structure, theoretical-chemistry, software, proteins

After minimizing a ligand (prepared with [MarvinSketch](https://chemaxon.com/marvin)) and preparing a target enzyme to dock said ligand onto (collected from [RCSP PDB — 5DGN (Crystal structure of human FPPS in complex with compound 13)](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/5DGN)), I was met with an error

```
ValueError: Could not find atomic number for Hn Hn
cannot prepare ligand for AutoDock Vina; please look in Reply Log and/or run Chimera with --…
```

[image: Reply Log]

As a new user to the Chimera software, I neither knew what `Hn Hn` meant or how to troubleshoot this issue. I can also attach the `mol` files for the minimized ligand and prepared target enzyme if necessary to help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Not sure about Chimera specifically, but a google search for Hn turns up either 'Azanylidene' or maybe the old name for Hassium (Hs) which was "hahnium" (Hn)?

Comment: @Thunderbolt114 - It's not the PDB file, that's for sure. Can you do `grep -A 5 -B 5 'Hn' minimized_file` and report what it says? It's going to turn out to be something involving a missing hydrogen added to a nitrogen is my guess, but let's have a look.

Comment: Is that a command I input into the software? If so, how can I input it? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It's a command for a Linux or UNIX shell searching for Hn and printing five lines before and after. Pretty much like the search box in a Texteditor, just not worth the unnecessary graphical interface.

Comment: I'd also assume that questions like this have a bigger audience at [mattermodeling.se]. Please be aware that cross posting is discouraged.

Comment: @Mas Again, `grep` is covered by one of the tutorials of [software carpentry](https://ucsbcarpentry.github.io/2021-08-09-ucsb-bash-online/07-find/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error for thyroxine (`T44.mol2`). Definitely two hydrogens on the amine nitrogen. From the `mol2` file:

```
     31 H6'        20.4230   40.7840   26.1950 H         1 T44    0.0000
     32 HN81       21.6870   45.6570   36.2000 H         1 T44    0.0000
     33 HN82       23.1470   46.0670   35.4150 H         1 T44    0.0000
     34 HO4'       22.9030   42.4090   22.4520 H         1 T44    0.0000
```

I presume these are the problem Hn Hn. Another `mol2` file, triiodothyronine, has the same lines, but doesn't have the error!

The problem is definitely the hydrogens on the nitrogen. However, it is with the writing of the `*.ligand.pdb` file. If, as above, the original `.mol2` (`.pdb`) file has `HN81` and `HN82` and `HO4'` all three will cause errors. The fix is the clean out the ligand's `.mol2` (or `.pdf`) file and just have the element symbol in columns 9 and 10. Problem fixed. If the element name is 4 characters long, the software writes the "H" in the wrong column, 9 not 10 of the `*.ligand.pdb` file, to get space.

Comment: Ahhh, what a wonderful, modern, flexible format .pdb is ...